# Releasing .NET Core 2.1 with angular 7 on Azure Web Apps - tries to run 'ng serve'

Tags: c#, angular, azure, angular7

I have just started creating a new .NET Core 2.1 project with Angular 7. Running it locally works perfect, on Azure Web Apps it fails to 'start' (while I am not sure if it should 'start' in the first place).

**Path dist index.html:** /ClientApp/dist/ClientApp/index.html

When I change the "Virtual applications and directories" within Application Settings of the webapp to site/wwwroot/ClientApp/dist/ClientApp then it does run but it then cannot call the actual .NET Core API methods. It also fails to load assets while they are in the same folder.

Why does this work perfectly fine locally and not in production. I will walk you through the configuration parts, you might spot a issue.

**Angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ClientApp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "less"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ClientApp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.less"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.less"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ClientApp-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ClientApp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "ClientApp:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ClientApp"
}
```

**Startup.cs** (just defaults)

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        ....
        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });

         ...
    }

     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        ....
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
        ...
    }
```

**VSTS / AzureDevOps:**

Build:

- it contains a .NET Core Build task, that is just pointing to the csproj.
- It contains a .NET Core Publish task:

[image: publish task]

Release:

- Just a standard deploy config:

[image: release config]

The error that is first produced is this:

> Error.
>   An error occurred while processing your request.
>   Request ID: |a1396e11-481dfbf3c3c010dc.
>
> Development Mode
>   Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.
>
> Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and restarting the application.

So, then I do what is requested and switch to development mode by adding **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** = Development.

Then this error pops up, basically saying it wants to start the app with npm build (and then executing ng serve). But the project is already build and ready for running, why does it want to fire up another webserver (on the webserver) like it would do in development?

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Now I could of course install angular-cli, but it doesn't seem the right thing to do, does it? Inside the **Startup.cs** it tells what the sourcePath is and there is actually a comment telling me about the production environment. Why is my app not running like normally?

**UPDATE 1:**

After Kirk Larkin's comment, disabling development environment and enabling logs, this was produced:

```
2018-11-27 12:17:03.259 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: The request path / does not match a supported file type
2018-11-27 12:17:03.259 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: The request path / does not match a supported file type
2018-11-27 12:17:03.607 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware: Request did not match any routes.
2018-11-27 12:17:03.609 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: The request path /index.html does not match an existing file
2018-11-27 12:17:03.628 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.
Your application is running in Production mode, so make sure it has been published, or that you have built your SPA manually. Alternatively you may wish to switch to the Development environment.

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Attach>b__1(HttpContext context, Func`1 next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Use>b__1(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
2018-11-27 12:17:03.721 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: The request path /Error does not match a supported file type
2018-11-27 12:17:03.721 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: The request path /Error does not match a supported file type
2018-11-27 12:17:03.727 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouter: Request successfully matched the route with name '(null)' and template 'Error'.
2018-11-27 12:17:03.744 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Initializing Razor view compiler with compiled view: '/Pages/Error.cshtml'.
2018-11-27 12:17:03.744 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Initializing Razor view compiler with compiled view: '/Pages/_ViewImports.cshtml'.
2018-11-27 12:17:03.745 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Located compiled view for view at path '/Pages/Error.cshtml'.
2018-11-27 12:17:03.820 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Could not find a file for view at path '/Pages/_ViewStart.cshtml'.
2018-11-27 12:17:03.828 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Could not find a file for view at path '/_ViewStart.cshtml'.
2018-11-27 12:17:03.900 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker: Route matched with {page = "/Error", action = "", controller = ""}. Executing action /Error
```

It says it cannot find a `index.html` or any supported filetype. I am now trying to update ht `Startup.cs` and point to ClientApp/dist/ClientApp for `rootPath`. Perhabs that helps

Comment: This one's a bit of a [Catch-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)). You have some sort of error in `Production`, so you switch to `Development`, but then when you're in `Development`, you call the `UseAngularCliServer` middleware setup and so you get a different error to the one you're actually trying to debug. If you've set up logging, have a look at that in `Production` mode and see what's happening.

Comment: One of those "ofcourse" moments, thanks. I have updated the question. It says it cannot find a `index.html` or any supported filetype. I am now trying to update ht startup.cs and point to `ClientApp/dist/ClientApp` for `rootPath`. Perhabs that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After @KirkLarkin's comment I was able to find the solution. I just had to change the `rootPath` to the location of the index.html

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    ....
    // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist/ClientApp";//change here
    });

     ...
}
```